# Terraform: Dynamically reference environment variables as values

Tags: templates, terraform, environment-variables, interpolation

How can I dynamically use the value of an environment variable as
a value in a Terraform resource, without having to declare a corresponding Terraform variable?

For example, imagine I declare a variable that contains a list of environment variable names:

```
variable "env_vars" {
    description = "A list of env vars to use"
}
```

And I define a `.tfvars` file that sets the value of that list:

```
env_vars = ["ENV_VAR_A", "ENV_VAR_B", "ENV_VAR_C"]
```

Then imagine some arbitrary resource with a `name` argument. I want to dynamically create 1 resource for each item in the `env_vars` list, with the value of `name` set to the **value** of the environment variable of the same name:

```
resource "arbitrary_thing" "thing" {
  count = length(var.env_vars)
  name = "<VALUE OF ENV VAR NAMED var.env_vars[count.index] >"
}
```

How can I correctly set that **name** value?

Comment: It's not possible. Such functionality is not supported in tf.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a supported functionality in Terraform.

However, HashiCorp (maintainers of Terraform) have posted a [support/help article](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4547786359571-Reading-and-using-environment-variables-in-Terraform-runs) on how you can achieve a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "arbitrary_thing" "thing" {
  count = length(var.env_vars)
  name =var.env_vars[count.index]
}

variable "env_vars" {
    description = "A list of env vars to use"
}

And I define a .tfvars file that sets the value of that list:

env_vars = ["ENV_VAR_A", "ENV_VAR_B", "ENV_VAR_C"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get the value of the environment variable with that name, not just the name from the list